# Software to make tree output humanly readable/browsable?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-search

For backup purposes I run such [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command)) commands:

```
tree /f /a > tree.txt
tree /a > treewof.txt
```

It looks like this in the textfile (this is treewof, without file names, just folder names).

```
|   +---Actions
|   \---Braid
+---Animated & Gif
|   +---Braid(Game)
|   +---My collection of 900 GIFs
|   +---RudeBootie
|   \---_Reaction
|       +---Abandon Thread_Fuck this shit
|       +---Adventure Time
|       +---Amazed_Excited_Nailed it
|       +---Cats_Pets_Animals
|       +---Children Demolition
|       +---Clapping
|       +---Community
|       +---Controversial (Upvote_Downvote)
|       +---Dancing
|       +---Deal with it
|       +---Didn't read lol
|       +---Disgust
```

And that's okay for this amount, but I got txt files as big as 4 mb, you can imagine how many entries there are. Thousand and thousand of entries.

I need a parser or browser or explorer that can make this .txt somehow humanely browsable (searchable would be a neat option, but no must).

For instance I'd like to open and close RudeBootie , Actions, etc. Not view the subfolders and files. But other times I want to do that.

Is there any software like that out there? Or better yet, if there's a software that can do indexes, just indexes of what's on a HDD up to and including single files, please mention them. All I need is a viewable/browseable file, that I can browse in case of dataloss, so I know WHAT I lost.